# while adding empty array and object, why console returns like this?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to print results for following combinations in chrome console. But could not able to understand results. why console returns following results. Can anyone please explain this?

```
[] + {} ==> "[object Object]"

{} + {} ==> "[object Object][object Object]"

{} + [] ==> 0

[] + [] ==> ""
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add two objects (arrays are objects too), js will call `toString` for you, so

```
 [] + {}
```

is actually:

```
 [].toString() + {}.toString()
```

Stringifying an array joins its elements, and as the array is empty it will be stringified to `""`. Objects are always stringified to `"[Object object]"`. That explains everything except:

```
 {} + []
```

... and thats a mistake on your side, it will return `"[Object object]"`

Comment: @ Jonas.  ... So what about this {} + [] ==> 0 ?

Comment: @gopigoppu have a look at the duplicate ... it depends if you are in an expression context or not